# AngularJS directive updating property of object on parent's scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am building a directive that is supposed to update its parent's scope. Basically this is what I want:

```
<div foo="foo.foo"></div>
```

This directive is supposed to set the model passed to the attribute "foo" to "bar". So the parent's scope is supposed to have something like:

```
$scope.foo = { foo: 'foo' };
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="fooController">
        {{ foo.foo }}
        <div foo="foo.foo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module( 'app', [] );

app.directive( 'foo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ( scope, attrs ) {
            scope[ attrs.foo ] = 'bar';
        }
    };
} );

app.controller( 'fooController', [ '$scope', function ( $scope ) {
    $scope.foo = {
        foo: 'foo'
    };
} ] );
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wphvc75k/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a 2-way binding for foo attributee, by using the '='

```
app.directive( 'foo', function () {
    return {
        scope : {
            foo: '='
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ( scope, attrs ) {
            console.log( scope );
            console.log( scope[ attrs.foo ] );
            scope.foo = 'bar';
        }
    };
} );
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hotbelgo/wphvc75k/1/)

Comment: Thank you, you're right! Actually I tried it and it wasn't working but in fact I wasn't looking at the right thing. My problem was coming from somewhere else :/